# Solving a parameterized matrix equation with specific structure

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, parametric, parameter-estimation, matrix-exponential

Consider the equation:

$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\Lambda_{\epsilon}C\Lambda_{\epsilon}^{\dagger}h}$, where
$\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ are $n$-length complex-vectors, $\mathbf{C}$ is a circulant $n\times n$ complex matrix, and $\mathbf{\Lambda_{\epsilon}}$ is a diagonal matrix with $\mathbf{\Lambda_{\epsilon}}(k) = \exp(i\frac{2\pi \epsilon}{n}k), k =0, 1 \ldots (n-1)$. ($\mathbf{\Lambda_{\epsilon}^{\dagger} = \Lambda_{-\epsilon}}$)

How can we solve for $\epsilon$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Since circulant matrices are diagonalized by DFT matrices, we can re-write the equation as $y_1 = \Lambda_{C}h_{1}$, where $y_1 = F\Lambda_{-\epsilon}y$ and $h_1 = F\Lambda_{-\epsilon}h$, $F$ is the inverse of the DFT-matrix and $\Lambda_{C}$ is the diagonal matrix of the DFT of the first row of $C$. In the new basis, the resulting equations appears simple, but I am not sure how to proceed. There appears to be a lot of structure, but I can't figure out how to lead it.

Comment: The system is obviously overdetermined, so in general a solution does not exist and you need some regularization like least squares, for example

Comment: If you consider $\hat y = F y, \hat h = F h$ then the equation is equivalent to $\hat y = T_\epsilon \Lambda_C T_\epsilon^\dagger \hat h$. Here $T_\epsilon = F \Lambda_\epsilon F^\dagger$. $T_\epsilon$ is a shift operator when $n \epsilon$ is integer.

Comment: @uranix Agree. Don't quite follow the shift-operator remark. $T_{\epsilon}$ is also circulant.

Comment: For integer $n\epsilon$ the circulant matrix $T_\epsilon$ is a cyclic permutation operator (maybe with some scaling factor).

Comment: See matrices $U, V$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Clifford_algebra#Matrix_representation